# Como puedo activar un objeto en Blender con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

Desde un script de Python deseo activar un objeto para así entrar al modo edición y editarlo. Para seleccionar el objeto deseado utilizo

```
bpy.context.scene.objects["Nombre_objeto"].select = True  # (1)
```

Lo que sucede es que si antes de seleccionar el objeto existe otro objeto activo, al momento de entrar en el modo edición con `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()`, entra al modo edición del objeto que estuvo activo anteriormente y no al del objeto seleccionado con (1).

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo dejar un objeto activo para editar sus propiedades.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias por la atención prestada.
Anexo código Python para correr en Blender, para que puedan ver a que me refiero exactamente.

```
###INICIO-CÓDIGO###

import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1, location=(-1,-2,0))
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()
nombre = 'c1'
bpy.context.object.name = nombre
bpy.data.objects[nombre].location=(1, 2, 0)


bpy.context.scene.objects["Esfera"].select = True
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
##<-- EJECUTAR SCRIPT -->##

###FIN-CÓDIGO###
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes marcar el objeto seleccionado como activo en esa escena usando el atributo [`active`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.SceneObjects.html#bpy.types.SceneObjects) de `SceneObjects`:

```
import bpy


bpy.context.scene.objects["Sphere"].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, implementando lo que me dijiste me surgió otra inquietud; cuando cambio el material de un objeto como puedo guardar esa acción en un keyframe, ya que la idea es que durante la animación los objetos cambien de material repetidas veces.

Comment: [en esta otra respuesta](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38626/65865) está actualizado a la versión 2.8+